# Struggling using mysqli num_rows

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

When I use this code:

```
<?php
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM families WHERE famname = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $e);
    $result = $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();
    $row_cnt = $result->num_rows;
    if($row_cnt == 0) {
        $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO families(famname) VALUES (?)");
        $stmt->bind_param('s', $e);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->close();
    }
?>
```

It gives me an error:

> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\fl\index.php on line 23

And when I `echo` the `$row_cnt` variable it also says:

> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\fl\index.php on line 23

How can I fix this to check the row count for the query and not to return an error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**mysqli_stmt::execute()**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.execute.php) is expected to return only TRUE or FALSE. To achieve your behavior follow the #1 example in [**this**](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) page.

Answer (score -1):

Oh I read a [note](https://www.php.net/mysqli_num_rows#105289) on PHP.net saying:

> If you have problems making work this num_rows, you have to declare ->store_result() first.

And I also changed the `$result->num_rows` to `$stmt->num_rows` thanks to @Kei.